# How to effectively store hour interval for every day in a year in relational database?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a campaign, for which I have to set up the hour intervals for every day in a year, in which it will be played, or not played.

For example:

will be played every day in a year except monday and on tuesday it woun't play from 7 to 9.30.

How can I effectively store the structure in SQL database? I have 365 days and 48 halfhour intervals. I don't want to use foreign keys to different tables, because it is inefficient.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a relational database if you're not going to use foreign keys?  That's kinda the whole point of a relational database.  If you don't need keys, just use a flat file.  Or use your favorite programming language such as php, java, or python.  All of them can handle the if/then/else structure you'd need to manage these intervals without creating a record in a table for each interval.

Comment: I need to use relational database because it is web application. I would like to avoid split this structure to multiple tables because it decreases the performance of queries, because in my case there will be hundreds (365*48) of rows only for 1 campaign. Imagine you have 100 campaigns, effectivness of such structure is very poor. That's why I am looking for a better solution within relational database.

Comment: Mysql can handle millions of rows just fine and is pretty fast even with joins involving several tables.  And no, you don't have to use a relational database for a web application.  PHP for instance can process a flat file just as easily as a database.  And if your database only has one table and will never have another table, then why use a database at all?  Another problem with having everything in one table is that you don't get any of the benefits of using a relational database.  One major one is reducing redundant data.

Comment: If you have a relational database you could have a table that would have all your intervals, and not have to have a single other record in that table ever and still related it to all the rest of your data.

Comment: If you use php for the interval logic, you wouldn't need to have a table of intervals at all.  You could just check the time against your requirements and if it fits, then run the code, if not, skip it.  That kind of structure is what programming languages are for.  SQL also supports if, then statements, though I personally prefer to use php for logic and sql for the queries.

Comment: I use J2EE, Spring and Hibernate... and I know that my DB inrastructure is pretty slow when handling big queries, especially if hibernate and its join mechanism is involved. I know I can do it with multiple tables and foreign keys, but I am looking for a clever mechanism.

Comment: Indexes can speed up slow queries depending on what you're trying to do.  Or else not using subqueries when you don't need to.  Anyway, if you want help here stop asking for a solution other than the solutions that work.  A solution that doesn't work isn't clever at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest table would look something like this. It *might* not be the best structure, because the end of the half-hour time segment isn't explicitly stored. Nevertheless . . .

```
create table campaign_times (
  campaign_name varchar(35) not null,
  time_segment timestamp not null,
  play boolean not null default true,
  primary key (campaign_name, time_segment)
);
```

I generated a bunch of random campaign names (about 175), and cross-joined those names with the half-hour intervals for the whole year: 3,083,520 rows.  I knew I'd need an index on time_segment. I also added an index for play, just in case PostgreSQL could use it.  (PostgreSQL has surprised me with its intelligent handling of low-selectivity columns more than once in the past.)

```
create index on campaign_times (time_segment);
create index on campaign_times (play);
```

Make sure the statistics are up-to-date.

```
analyze campaign_times;
```

Now let's see how bad this situation really is.

```
explain analyze
select *
from campaign_times 
where current_timestamp between time_segment and time_segment + interval '30 minutes'
  and play = true;

"Index Scan using campaign_times_time_segment_idx on campaign_times  
[snip]
"Total runtime: 498.713 ms"
```

Less than half a second to get the current play list from a table of 3 million rows. And without thinking about optimizations like deleting old rows, trying more thoughtful indexes, storing *fewer* rows (like only a month ahead of today's date), etc.

I can live with that.

---

In production, I'd want foreign keys and check constraints. These don't affect the speed of SELECT statements in PostgreSQL, and I don't *think* they affect SELECT speed in MySQL. (Well, check constraints surely don't, because MySQL doesn't enforce them anyway.)